# Populating LongListSelector GridCellSize with dynamic values

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Ok, I want my **LongListSelector** to render grids. Two grid items for each row. I don't want to set the width and height in pixel size since it's important for me that they cover the page.

If I know how many grid items I need to render I always do like this.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Now I can add the grid and set row and column for the items. In this case though, I use the **LongListSelector** so I don't know how to go around this problem. I know I can set the **GridCellSize="value, value"** but as far as I know, it's only for pixels.

If there's someone who know how to solve this, please answer,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the items in the LLS will be assigned the height the item requires to render, the only way to ensure it fills the whole screen will be to set an explicit height.
Note that you'll need to account for the different screen resolutions.

Comment: Thanks for the clearification. Then I dont'f feel bad when setting the  GridCellSize from codebehind :)